# Backbone - built-in REST capability

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am confused by Backbone's built-in REST capability. I was under the impression that Backbone models, upon a `model.save()`, would automatically append the value identified by idAttribute to the end of the urlRoot. But I see a lot of examples online, like the one below, where the application imperatively appends the the id to the url. Why is that? Which one is better?

An example using RequireJS:

```
  define(function(require) {
        var Backbone = require('Backbone');

        return Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            url: function() {
                return this.urlRoot + '?name=' + this.id;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone assumes that you were following some common REST practices while you were designing your REST API.

For instance, an API which updates a user should be exposed as:

```
PUT /users/:id
```

rather than

```
PUT /users?id=:id
```

Of course there are some edge cases when you must rewrite the default URL function but, in general, leaving it as is means you were following the best practices while designing your REST API.

One case I can think of when rewrites are necessary is when a sub-resource is identified by multiple IDs:

```
PUT /apps/:appId/schedules/:scheduleId
```

then the `url` function will be:

```
url: function () {
    return this.urlRoot + '/' + this.appId + '/schedules/' + this.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When applying REST, the id is typically the unique identifier of an item that is contained by a collection (expressed in plural). 
The url `/greeting/id` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Parameters sent via the query string (behind the question mark) serve as `filters` to the collection that is currently queried.